# URL Rewriting IIS6 a URL instead of another URL

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

i have a .net application, currently siting on my local pc. the url now for my application:

```
http://localhost/foooz/portal/login.aspx
```

how do i can connect a web instance to the URL above instead of URL below:

```
http://localhost/foooz
```

can i just keying `http://localhost/foooz` and it will direct bring me to `http://localhost/foooz/portal/login.aspx` ???

Comment: try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2538/URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

Use below :

In Windows 20008, IIS 7.0

Administrative Tools-> IIS Manager -> You Server Name -> Your site name -> Under HTTP features -> Default document -> Add login.aspx

Or

Put the following in site's or application's web.config file:

```
>    <system.webServer>
>         <defaultDocument>
>            <files>
>                <add value="~/Default.aspx"/>
>            </files>
>         </defaultDocument>
>     </system.webServer>
```

or

**Use Form authentication**,Form authentication is cookie based, as ASP.NET places a cookie in the client machine in order to track the user. If the user requests a secure page and has not logged in, then ASP.NET redirects him/her to the login page. Once the user is authenticated, he/she will be allowed to access the requested page.

Comment: this link may helpful to you http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true